# What is the mass of Photon or Light Particle?

Tags: visible-light, photons, mass, speed-of-light, radiation

We know that any particle moving at speed of light will have infinite mass.

Since even Light has particles. Then what is the size of the Particle? How to imagine this with the mass of light particles.

Comment: Recommended reading: [The shape and size of a photon](https://readingfeynman.org/2014/09/16/the-size-and-shape-of-a-photon/)

Comment: We know that any particle moving at the speed of light has ZERO mass.

Comment: In that article I read: "But an electromagnetic wave is not like a ‘probability wave’. So… Do they have a de Broglie wavelength as well?"
Yes it is and of course they do. This is where De Broglie got the idea.

Comment: We know that any particle moving at speed of light will have infinite mass. Would it not hurt a bit, when you looked at any light source, if this were correct?

Comment: *"We know that any particle moving at speed of light will have infinite mass."* It is worth thinking about the (possibly unstated) assumptions of whatever "proof" of this "fact" you've read. Do you see the loophole?

Answer (score 2):

The mass of a photon is anywhere between zero and $10^{-18} ~ eV/c^2$.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon

No need to write photon or light with capitals, by the way.

Comment: This is a funny way to state the experimental upper limit on the photon's mass, because it suggests that the probability distribution is uniform. The most likely value for the photon mass is *zero*. The limit $10^{-18}\,\mathrm{eV}/c^2$ is where a massive photon would affect the way the sun's magnetic field interacts with the solar wind. Making the same sort of argument on the scale of galactic magnetic fields apparently reduces the upper limit by eight or ten orders or magnitude! For details, see the [Particle Data Group review](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2018/listings/rpp2018-list-photon.pdf).

Comment: @rob I do not understand.  1) Stating a range does not suggest a uniform probability distribution per your own reference. 2) The Particle Group Review states the same limit that I quoted from wikipedia.

Comment: Fair enough (1) The "anywhere" is what suggested to me the uniform probability distribution. Compare to my prediction that your height is anywhere between zero and one thousand meters. Technically correct, but the upper limit sets the wrong scale: I could be talking about a person or a mountain. (2) My link is the *source* for the Wikipedia article.

Comment: @rob This is misleading. You _know_ that my length is in much smaller range. You don't know that the photon mass is in a smaller range. You may _like_ the idea that the photon has zero mass but you don't know that it is not somewhere else in the range specified by the particle group. No one does. Thus is why they specify this range.

Comment: I would agree with you if there weren't reasonable arguments for a [much smaller limit](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.98.010402), but the reasons those arguments don't set the PDG limit are too complex for a comment. I would be okay if you had said something like "most likely zero, but could be as large as $10^{-26}\rm\,eV$ without destroying the galactic magnetic field. Changes in our assumptions about just quite what a photon is could make the mass as large as $10^{-18}\rm\,eV$."

Comment: @rob I just adopt the number from the particle data group, but I am aware that smaller upper limits have been argued.

Answer (score 0):

Massive objects simply can not move at the speed of light. Light, or photons, are mass-less particles. They have 0 mass - which is why they can (and have to) move at the speed of light.

Answer (score 0):

From the **special relativity theory** you got the usefull relationship

$$E^2 = \Big(m\cdot c^2 \Big)^2 + \Big(p \cdot c  \Big)^2 \quad .$$

All experimental results up to now show that $m=0$ for a photon. Therefore

$$E^2 = 0 + (p\cdot c)^2 \\
E = p\cdot c = \hbar \cdot {k} \cdot c = \hbar\cdot \omega$$

**BTW**: In my opinion it is false to talk about **relativistic masses** as you did in your post. The  mass is **invariant**!

The equation can be simple derived by using the equation for a relativistic **moment**

$$ p = \cfrac{m\cdot v}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}} \qquad ,$$

and the **relativistic energy**

$$ E = \cfrac{m\cdot c^2}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}} \qquad .$$